# jQuery AJAX syntax error, unexpected token: ':'

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Trying to make my first AJAX call to an API. When run Firefox's console returns `SyntaxError: unexpected token: ':'` with a link to the [MDN docs about missing a semi-colon](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Errors/Missing_semicolon_before_statement?utm_source=mozilla&utm_medium=firefox-console-errors&utm_campaign=default).

```
$.ajax({
  type: "GET",
  url: "url/to/API/here",
  dataType: "jsonp",
  jsonp: "callback",
  success: function(data){
    console.log(data.quoteText);
  },
  xhrFields: {
    withCredentials: false
  }
})
```

Following some other similar issues I've tried using JSON and not JSONP, but returns a CORS error (specifically `CORS header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' missing`) also tried using [CrossOrigin](https://crossorigin.me/) to no avail either.

Comment: If the server just returns JSON, you cannot use JSONP.

Comment: Your API has to support JSONP for you to use it (you can't just use it with a JSON response, it's not the same thing). Refer to their documentation to see whether it does, and if so how you tell it that's what you want.

Comment: what you get by direct from browser `url/to/API/here` ?